# Reducing a list of repeated tuples and counting repeats

Tags: python, list

I was wondering how to reduce a list of tuples like the following:

```
[('a','b'),('b','a'),('c','d')]
```

to the following:

```
[('a','b'),('c','d')]
```

And also count the number of times an element repeats and return a list that associates the count with the tuple. From this example, that list would be [2, 1]

Thanks!

---

I've tried:

```
l = [('a','b'),('c','d')]
counts_from_list = [len(list(group)) for group in itertools.groupby(my_list)]
zip(set(l), counts_from_list)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects), sorting the items first to make sure `('a', 'b')` and `('b', 'a')` are the "same".

```
>>> data = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c','d')]
>>> data = [tuple(sorted(x)) for x in data]
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> c = Counter(data)
>>> c
Counter({('a', 'b'): 2, ('c', 'd'): 1})
```

Accessing the data

```
>>> c.keys()
[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd')]
>>> c.values()
[2, 1]
>>> c.items()
[(('a', 'b'), 2), (('c', 'd'), 1)]
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that.

Answer (score 0):

Use `set` for to check tuples regardless to order of their items.

```
my_list = [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c','d')]
my_list = map(set, my_list)
```

and Instead of

```
counts_from_list = [len(list(group)) for group in itertools.groupby(my_list)]
```

You should use

```
counts_from_list = [len(list(value)) for group, value in itertools.groupby(my_list)]
```

because `itertools.groupby(my_list)` returns key, value pairs

but I would advise You to use collections.Counter

```
collections.Counter(map(frozenset, [('a','b'),('b','a'),('c','d')])).values()
```

`set` is not appropriate here because it is not hashable.